# How to pass string values from Class file to Mvc Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here i'm using Repo Class in that i wrote some Logic.When that Logic success I want to pass that string msg to mvc controller please Help me

**Repo.cs**

```
 public void validateUser(Auth aut)
        {
            var xx=aut.Email;
            var xr=db.Auths.Where(rr=>rr.Email == xx).FirstOrDefault();

            if (xr != null)
            {
                var x = (from n in db.Auths
                         where n.Email == xr.Email && n.Password == xr.Password
                         select n).FirstOrDefault();
                if (x != null)
                {
                    var xz = (from n in db.Auths
                             where n.Email == xr.Email && n.Password == xr.Password && n.Active == aut.Active
                             select n).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (xz != null)
                    {
                        string Acc = "Your Account Activated....";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {string ddd = "Your Account not Activated....";}}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
      Repo objrepo = new Repo();

 public ActionResult Login(Auth aut)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               objrepo.validateUser(aut);
                ViewBag.Success = "Success.....";

            }
            else
                ViewBag.msg = "Invalid.....";
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You are calling that method from your controller so just need to user return type as `string` and return what every you want to return in string

Comment: Returning something from a class is pretty much universal. First you create an object of that class. Then you call the method that returns what you want to return. You method must meet certain criteria.public methodReturnType methodName(methodInputsIfAny){body code; return somthingThatMatchesMethodReturnType;}

Comment: Sedrick Jefferson could u plz mention some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public string validateUser(Auth aut)
    {
    string result = "Invalid Email Address ....";

        var xx=aut.Email;
        var xr=db.Auths.Where(rr=>rr.Email == xx).FirstOrDefault();

        if (xr != null)
        {
        result = "Invalid Password ....";

            var x = (from n in db.Auths
                     where n.Email == xr.Email && n.Password == xr.Password
                     select n).FirstOrDefault();
            if (x != null)
            {
            result = "Your Account is not Activated ....";

                var xz = (from n in db.Auths
                         where n.Email == xr.Email && n.Password == xr.Password && n.Active == aut.Active
                         select n).FirstOrDefault();
                if (xz != null)
                {
                    result = "Your Account Activated....";
                }
            }
        }
    return result;
    }
```

And this:

```
 public ActionResult Login(Auth aut)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           string result = objrepo.validateUser(aut);
            ViewBag.Success = result;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thank u Soo much Mr nocturns

Answer (score 0):

Change return type from void to string in validateUser method of repo.cs file.
Return message from method to controller.

i.e.
**In controller file**

```
public ActionResult Login(Auth aut)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
               ViewBag.msg = objrepo.validateUser(aut);
            else
                ViewBag.msg = "Invalid.....";
            return View();
        }
```

Use **ViewBag.msg** in view file.

Thanks,
Hiral Shah

Comment: but how i will show him Like Your A/c not Activated...or your Account  not valied ....could u please write the code

Comment: ViewBag.msg = objrepo.validateUser(aut);   its Througing an error as cant implecitly convert void to Dynamic

Comment: You have to return `string` from your method as you have void type